# Java applet viewer goes blank after showing the image

Tags: java, c++, applet

I have a sample C++ program using a graphics library. It invokes the java applet but it shows the image only for a second and goes blank. The programs works fine on other systems. I have changed various jvm versions but still result is the same. I am using ubuntu platform.

There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /opt/ibm/java-i386-70/jre/bin/java              1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1         manual mode
```

Can someone help in resolving this issue.

Sample Code....It invokes java applet and displays image only for a second and then goes blank.

```
#include <iostream>
#include"gwindow.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    GWindow gw;
  cout << "This program draws a diamond, rectangle, and oval." << endl;
  double width = gw.getWidth();
  double height = gw.getHeight();
  gw.drawLine(0, height / 2, width / 2, 0);
  gw.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width, height / 2);
  gw.drawLine(width, height / 2, width / 2, height);
  gw.drawLine(width / 2, height, 0, height / 2);
  gw.setColor("BLUE");
  gw.fillRect(width / 4, height / 4, width / 2, height / 2);
  gw.setColor("GRAY");
  gw.fillOval(width / 4, height / 4, width / 2, height / 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Ajay.

Comment: What is the code of the applet?

Comment: Also.. what is your question?

Comment: Hello Andrew...I have edited the question.Sorry for not being clear

Comment: What is a `GWindow`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi Andrew...There is no problem with the code..It works fine on other computers...I am learning to use graphics library through "Programming abstractions - Stanford COurse". They have a lot of dependencies, so I can't post all the dependencies. Here is the link for a short description http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/                the code invokes a java applet and it shows the image for a second and after that it goes blank. I think there is a small issue with my  java installation but I have tried many JVM's without a good result.

Comment: *"There is no problem with the code..It works fine on other computers"*  Other computers may be running a JRE that does not expose the bug.